# TextView элемент не отображается на экране эмулятора

Tags: java, android-studio, xml, textview

Создал пустое окно, добавил один лишь текстовый элемент, который не отображается на экране. Подскажите, из-за чего?

**P.S.** Когда я устанавливаю текст через `.setText`, то он отображается

---

**xml приложения:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Привет, мир!" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**java-код:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mainText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `tools:text` на `android:text`.

Comment: @SurfaceStack это сработало, спасибо! :)
Скажите, каждый раз так будет необходимо менять или можно где-то это настроить?

Comment: Всегда так надо писать.

Comment: `tools:text` используется для показа текста во время верстки на визуализаторе, `android:text` - для показа уже на реальном устройстве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tools:text` присваивает текст только для показа на макете во время разработки.
Чтобы присвоить текст непосредственно TextView, нужно использовать `android:text`.
Например `android:text="Привет, мир!"`